# How to call my smart contract with geth mobile API?

Tags: go-ethereum, android, ios

I want to create a static library using cgo and geth mobile API and consume it from iOS and Android native code.

I used the abigen command to generate Go source code for Go Contract Bindings.
However, it is not possible to specify whether to use the normal geth API or the geth mobile API with the abigen command.

When using the geth Mobile API, for example the import statement

```
import(
    ethereum "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    ...
)
```

of

```
import(
    ethereum "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/mobile"
)
```

Should I rewrite it as

Comment: For example, the mobile API struct EthereumClient has the struct ethclient.Client as a member.
The name indicates that it is for mobile, so if you want to make the contract mobile, it seems that you need to manually modify the go source generated by the command abigen.